# AVPlayer - m3u8 works in simulator but not on a device?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Is there *any* way to debug AVPlayer?

`player.error` is nil, and my playlist plays fine in the simulator. I see from my web server that the first few segments are downloaded, and then the rest aren't.

I get no video or audio, and I'm not sure how to debug what's happening.

Comment: got a link to an offending m3u8?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar problem with a m3u8 that worked previously with MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @ÞorvaldurRúnarsson I found no way to debug avplayer, but if you have valid mpeg-ts segments with correct discontinuities, VLC will play your video. If VLC can't play your video, iOS won't either at some point.

Comment: Hi, has anyone find a solution ? It works on simulator but not on apple tv (tvos 15). I can make it work with vlc